# Execute scripts in folder

Tags: powershell

I want to execute all of the scripts (`.ps1` files) inside a specific directory.

My script is as follows:

```
$fileEntries = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles("c:\scripts"); 
foreach($fileName in $fileEntries) 
{ 
   $fileName 
}
```

The body of the loop would have to change. What should I change it to execute the scripts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the call operator (&) to execute the scripts:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\scripts -Filter *.ps1 | ForEach-Object {& $_.FullName}
```

Comment: Just as a side note: I have associated ps1 with powershell and my box and I just do `ii *.ps1`

Comment: Wow, that association also meant that double-clicking on a Powershell script invoked it. So simple that I almost feel stupid :)